# Passing variables to functions in C

Tags: c, function, variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
//function prototype
double triangle(double b ,double h);
//main function
int main(void)
{
    //declare variables
    double height,base, ans;
    //take input
    printf("Please give the height of the triangle:");
    scanf("%d",&height);
    printf("Please give the base of the triangle:");
    scanf("%d",&base);
    //pass variables to triangle function and equal returned value to ans
    ans = triangle(base,height);
    //prdouble returned doubleeger
    system("CLS");
    system("COLOR C");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tThe area of the triangle is: %d\n\n\n", ans );
    return 0;
}
//area function
double triangle(double b, double h)
{
    printf("Hello");
    //declare varible 
    double a;
    //process data
    a = (b*h)/2;
    //return ans to main
    return (a);

}
```

Above is the code for a program to compute the area of a triangle, but while it works when I use integers, when I try to use doubles it fails to run the "triangle" function. Could I get some advice on why this is?

Comment: How does it fail to run a function? What are the characteristics of this failure?

Comment: You need to use `%lf` instead of `%d` format to read into `double`.  Using `%d` indicates to `scanf()` that the pointer is an `int *`; using `%lf` indicates it is a `double *`.  Also remember to print your inputs for checking; this would have told you a lot about what's going wrong.  And if your compiler wasn't warning you about the mismatch between the format string and the pointers, it is time to turn on the warnings, or get a better compiler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler isn't `%f` the specifier for double? This seems to indicate that http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Comment: @BobbySacamano: for `printf`, yes - floats and doubles are treated the same. But for `scanf`, no - you need `%f` for `float` and `%lf` for `double`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, my bad! Can you tell me the difference between %i and %d then?

Comment: @BobbySacamano: it is a significant difference between `printf()` and `scanf()` — a source of endless problems.  With `printf()`, the `%f` format serves for both `double` and `float` because the compiler automatically converts `float` to `double` in the call.  You can now use `%lf` for `double` in `printf()`, mainly for symmetry with `scanf()`.  In `scanf()`, `%f` indicates a `float *` argument; `%lf` indicates a `double *` argument.  You use `%Lf` in both `printf()` and `scanf()` to indicate `long double` (but the types are `long double` and `long double *`, of course).

Comment: @CallumHunt: `%i` supports hexadecimals, decimals and octals, `%d` only decimals.

Comment: `%i` accepts `0xABCD` as a hex and `007` as octal and 1234 as decimal; `%d` only accepts decimal (and `%x` only accepts hex and doesn't require the `0x` prefix, and `%o` only accepts octal and doesn't require the 0 prefix).

Comment: As a side note, you should get into the habit of checking the result of `scanf`. It will return the number of items successfully scanned (in your case, 1). If `scanf` doesn't return 1, then it means the user did not enter valid input. If `scanf` fails, you are relying on uninitialised values, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I was under the impression that integer couldn't take decimals, so really double/ float is only useful in really large numbers?

Comment: You should check `scanf` for [Errors](http://ideone.com/h9z5ye).

Answer (score 2):

`%d` as format string of `scanf` is used for `int` values. For `float` values you need `%f` (or `%lf` for `double`s).

A mismatch between format string and pointer type is "undefined behavior" and can lead to all kind of errors (or even just work in some cases).

Answer (score 2):

Use `%lf` to read `double` numbers:

```
scanf("%lf",&height);
scanf("%lf",&base);
```

Use `%f` to print `double` or `float` variables:

```
printf("\n\n\t\t\tThe area of the triangle is: %f\n\n\n", ans );
```

Answer (score 1):

`%d` is actually used for integer despite looking like it might represent double (I like to think of `%d` as digit) .

`%f` is used for floating point numbers.

`%lf` is used for double type. double is a type of float with double the number of bits. double usually has 64 bits and float is usually 32 bits.  The `l` is a length modifier for the larger type. (I like to remember it as 'long float'.)

Comment: What you've actually said is correct, but the way you said it has the potential to mislead.  If you said _While it might seem plausible that `%d` would be used for `double`, it is …_  that would have less chance of misleading. That is somewhat a matter of emphasis.  I'd go with a more direct _Despite anything you may think to the contrary, the `%d` format specifier is used for decimal integers (with `%x` for hexadecimal and `%o` for octal) and `%lf` is used for `double` values._

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what "fails" means in your question I would try and change your `scanf` statements to use the double format specifier `%lf` rather than `%d`.

```
scanf("%lf", &height);
```

Answer (score 0):

as others have said, you need to change the type that you neeed to take from the user.

```
scanf("%lf %lf", &height, &base);
```

this should do the trick.
good luck M8.

P.S
"%lf" and "%f", both give you the same result. six digits of precision after the decimal point.